# Is there a word for the chants animals do in order to attract a sexual mate?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for the chants animals do in order to attract a sexual mate? I am thinking there might be an adjective or noun for this, but I have no idea what it might be.

Comment: What animals? There are all sorts of sounds that animals make. Do you mean birds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are talking about a ["mating call"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mating_call).

Comment: You should include the definition (and provide attribution) in this answer. Giving a link-only answer is frowned upon—and sometimes deleted.